# Using an extra variable for sorting within a filter javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am in a confusing situation, I am filtering an array and sorting them, but I need to filter in such a way that I can access the variable.

```
products.filter(function(product) {
   // some product have primaryName some second name, need to sort by primaryName if there is one, 
   var universalName = product.attr('primaryName') || product.attr('name');
   return product; 
   })
   .sort(function (a,b) {
         // how do I sort here so that primaryName is sorted too if there is one, so how can I access variable universalName here? 
         return a.attr('name').localeCompare(b.attr('name'));
```

As you can see I need to sort by primaryName if there is one, if there is no primaryName just sorting by name which is always there. I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Do the *entries* in the list vary which one they have, or is it just that all entries in the list will have `primaryName` in some cases, and in other cases all entries in the list will have `name`?

Comment: All entries will have `name` for sure, but some of them have `primaryName` so if some of them do have `primaryName` need to include that instead of `name` for sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I access variable universalName here?

You can't, there were as many `universalName` vars as there were entries (one is created for each call to `filter`'s callback), and they were all private to the callback and removed before `sort` is called.

If the entries have a mix, the simplest thing is probably just to repeat your `||`:

```
products.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a.attr('primaryName') || a.attr('name')).localeCompare(b.attr('primaryName') || b.attr('name'));
});
```

or with easier reading/debugging (any decent JavaScript engine will optimize this to the above anyway):

```
products.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aname = a.attr('primaryName') || a.attr('name');
    var bname = b.attr('primaryName') || b.attr('name');
    return aname.localeCompare(bname);
});
```

Note that I've removed your `.filter` entirely, since it keeps all entries, so there's no need for it.

---

**Not** for your situation, but just for completeness: Sometimes, if a check is really expensive and it's important to avoid repeating it, it's worth taking a pass through the array to do the check and map the entry to a tuple with the original entry plus the value, then sort, then map again to go back to the original form, like this:

```
products
    .map(function(product) {
        return {product: product, name: product.attr('primaryName') || product.attr('name')};
    })
    .sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
    })
    .map(function(entry) {
        return entry.product;
    });
```

or in ES2015+

```
products
    .map(product => ({product, name: product.attr('primaryName') || product.attr('name')}))
    .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
    .map(({product}) => product);
```

but there's no need for that overhead with your `a.attr('primaryName') || a.attr('name')` check.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is your best solution, but looks like your `filter` is not a `filter` actually you are looping over the array, so it would be better to use `map` instead of `filter` and add the `universalName` to the object.

and to answer your question, if you don't save the value on the object, you wont be able to use it, because the scope of each variable is the function, in the case you created `var universalName` it will only live on the scope of `function(product)` which is the callback of the `filter` function, so it wont be any variable called `universalName` inside the `sort` callback function.

check a working example

```js
//disordered products.
var products = [{
    primaryName: 'test'
  },

  {
    name: 'test7'
  },
  {
    primaryName: 'test3'
  },
  {
    name: 'test4'
  },
  {
    name: 'test5'
  },
  {
    primaryName: 'test1'
  },
  {
    primaryName: 'test2'
  },

  {
    name: 'test6'
  },
]
var filtered = products.map(function(product) {
    var universalName = product['primaryName'] || product['name'];
    product.universalName = universalName;
    return product;
  })
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    return a['universalName'].localeCompare(b['universalName']);
  });

//ordered by universalName;
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: You have to be pretty careful putting expando properties on elements, I wouldn't recommend this, with the check the OP's doing being so cheap.